# How to reactivate windows 7 ultimate with OEM key

Tags: laptop, product-key, oem

Unfortunately I uninstalled windows 7 product key with command prompt.

Windows 7 came with an OEM key preinstalled on my HP ProBook 640 G1.

When I retype the OEM product key, it shows some character as invalid.

Please help me to reactivate windows.

Answer (score -1):

If Windows 7 is not detecting automatically the preinstalled OEM key,
then it is not burnt into the BIOS. This is one problem.

If you have made a mistake when writing down the OEM key, this is a second problem.
Try to find the correct key by logic.
Or as this is OEM, you should have a sticker on the computer with
the correct key, so try not to make mistakes when typing it.

Otherwise, if you don't have any of the above, your only hope is to call
HP Support or Microsoft Support.
Be aware that after January 14, 2020, Microsoft will no longer provide
security updates or support for PCs running Windows 7.

Comment: Produkey shows OEM(bios) key and when I copy and paste into activator it says some character as invalid

Comment: Please **don't** show this number here. Is it possible that you have a blank at the end or something similar? Copy it inside Notepad to examine. If you can't see anything then try another [alternative to Produkey](https://alternativeto.net/software/produkey/), but be careful to refuse any additional software offers during the installation.